# Importing multiple modules with same named functions without namespace conflict

Tags: python, import, module, namespaces

Say I have two Python modules with identically named functions,

```
# module_a.py

def fun1(...):
   do something

def fun2(...):
   do something with fun1
```

```
# module_b.py

def fun1(...):
   do something else

def fun2(...):
   do something else with this fun1
```

Now if I `from module_a import *` then `from module_b import *`, the functions from module_a will be removed from the namespace and only those from module_b will remain. My question is, if I instead use

```
import module_a
import module_b
```

what is the behaviour of `module_b.fun2` and `module_a.fun2`? Does `module_b.fun2` call `module_b.fun1` internally, and `module_a.fun2` call `module_a.fun1`, as we would expect if we just imported one of the modules (not the other) and then called <that_module>.fun2? If not, how do I deal with this scenario (i.e. be able to import both and call something like `module_a.fun2` to generate the same effect as from scratch `import module_a; module_a.fun2()`, and `module_b.fun2` to generate the same effect as from scratch `import module_b; module_b.fun2()`) - assuming for whatever reason that changing the code in module_a and module_b, e.g., to make function names non-identical, is not possible?

Comment: The namespace of a module is independent of the namespaces of other modules, including the namespaces of the modules that happens to import it. Writing `import module_b` has absolutely no affect on the namespace of `module_a`.

Comment: So the output of `import module_a; module_a.fun2()` is expected to remain unchanged if we also `import module_b` with its own `module_b.fun1` and `module_b.fun2`, before we call `module_a.fun2()`?

Comment: Mobeus Zoom: Yes, but you will have to prefix the contents of items in each with the module name, i.e. `module_b.fuc2()`. This is by-design precisely to prevent namespace collisions.